# How to recover removed elements to before of removing position in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Less if more, so I put my code here: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vahids/zqrc5em6/)

User can select paragraphs and remove by pressing remove button. after that Undo button will be appear. I used .append for recover removed paragraph but they append end of all paragraphs.

What's your suggestion to recovery removed elements to the befor self position ?

---

in HTML file I work in .lead class:

```
        <div class="lead">

        </div>
```

In CSS I .selectedRow background color changed:

```
body{
    background: #e3e3e3;
}
.selectedRow{
    background-color: rgba(30,30,30,.3);
}

#jQueryBtnUndo, #jQueryBtnAdd, #jQueryBtnRemove{
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```

And in jQuery :

```
var undo;

var main = function(){
    $('.lead').append(
        $('<p>').text('New Paragraph'),
        $('<p>').text('New Paragraph'),
        $('<p>').text('New Paragraph'),
        $("<div class='btn btn-larg btn-primary' id='jQueryBtnAdd'>").text('Add'),
        $("<div class='btn btn-larg btn-primary' id='jQueryBtnRemove'>").text('Remove'),
        $("<div class='btn btn-larg btn-primary' id='jQueryBtnUndo'>").text('Undo')
        );
    $('#jQueryBtnUndo').hide();
}


$(document).on('click', '#jQueryBtnAdd', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.lead').append(
        $('<p>').text('New Paragraph')
        );
});

$(document).on('click', '#jQueryBtnRemove', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
        undo = $('.selectedRow').remove();
        undo.removeClass('selectedRow');
        console.log(undo);
        $('#jQueryBtnUndo').show('slow/400/fast', function() {

        });
});

$(document).on('click','#jQueryBtnUndo', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
        $('.lead').append(undo);
        $('#jQueryBtnUndo').hide('slow/400/fast', function() {

        });
});

$(document).on('click', '.lead p', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).toggleClass('selectedRow');
});

$(document).ready(main);
```

Comment: instead of `removing` use `detach` and which detaches the element but helps to keep the details of element which can be put back using `attach`

Comment: If it is temporary, it not advisable to `remove` and `append`. Instead use `show()` and `hide()`. It is convenient for us and the browser as well.

Comment: @VinodKumar, Show / Hide working well. what If I wan't to remove paragraph for ever ?!

Comment: @GuruprasadRao, detach working but I can't reattach. There are no any attach or reattach methods. and If I use append It's gone put It end of list.

Comment: You could remove it then... You don't have to know the position of the removed paragraph anymore!

Comment: I think this can be now typical  `xy problem`..

Comment: @GuruprasadRao, at less I learn about XY problem now :D . Thanks for help.

Comment: Anytime.. Happy coding..☺

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use `show()`/`hide()` if it temporary.

However, if you need to only remove and append then you could store the position of the paragraph (index) as a self-contained attribute and you could check that when appending.

Say something like this:

```
function detach(para) {
    var parent = para.parentNode;
    for(var c=0; c<parent.childNodes.length; c++) {
       if(parent.childNodes[c] == para) {
          para.setAttribute("paraPosition", c);
          break;
       }
    }
    return para;
}
function attach(para) {
    var parent = document.getElementById("parentId");
    var position = para.getAttribute("paraPosition");
    var nextElement = parent.childNodes[position];//Next element would have taken this place.
    if(nextElement) {
        para.insertBefore(nextElement);
    }
    else {
        parent.appendChild(para);
    }
    return para;
}
```

However, you may face a logical error on this detach and attach method.
That is:

```
Say initially you 5 divs   [0,1,2,3,4];
You detach para "3"        [0,1,2,4];    //Now para "3" stores it position as 3.
You detach para "4"        [0,1,2];      //Now para "4" stores it position as 3.
Now you attach "3"         [0,1,2,3];
Now you attach "4"         [0,1,2,4,3];  // THIS HAPPENS AS YOU STORE "4"'s position as 3.
```

On the other hand `Show`/`Hide` is more reliable.

Comment: so I choice Show/Hide . what's your idea to how to remove paragraphs for real ?! because after refreshing page. they're gone be visible again.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you. You mean, once you refresh the page, you don't want the paragraphs anymore?